# Component systems: No inheritance hierarchy at all, or a basic one?

Tags: architecture, oop

*(I asked a similar question, but it had more questions inside it and I feel it wasn't clear enough, so I'm opening a new one).*

Until recently I implemented all my games using an inheritance hierarchy. Those were simple games.

For example:

```
          Entity
          /    \
      Movable  Static
      /  \        /  \
    Orc  Mage   Tree  Wall
```

This worked for simple games.

However recently I read about 'entity component systems'. Using this approach, a class doesn't inherit from another class in order to receive functionality. Instead it is composed with it, which allows for more flexible designs.

My question is this:

I know that each component is a class (derived from a common base class).

However, there is one thing I don't understand: In the 'component system' approach, is there **one** class that all entities are instances of - and the only difference between entities is the components they contain?

For example: There is a class `Entity`. All entities in the game are instances of this class.

The only differences between them is that they are composed with different `Component` objects.

For example:

```
Component aiComponent = new AIComponent();
Component movementComponent = new MovementComponent();
Component physicsComponent = new PhysicsComponent();
Component rangedAttackComponent = new RangedAttackComponent();

Entity orc = new Entity();
orc.addComponent(aiComponent);
orc.addComponent(movementComponent);
orc.addComponent(physicsComponent);

Entity shootingCastle = new Entity();
orc.addComponent(aiComponent);
orc.addComponent(rangedAttackComponent);
orc.addComponent(physicsComponent);
```

As you can see, both `orc` and `shootingCastle` are instances of the `Entity` class. But they are composed with different components.

Is this how 'entity component systems' are supposed to be? **No inheritance hierarchy at all?** **Or is there still a basic inheritance hierarchy, but most of the logic is inside components?**

Comment: This doesn't look significantly different from your first question to me. The answers would certainly be essentially the same ("it depends").

Comment: It does seem you put more thought into this question though. I would reccomend updating the first one since it seems you have narrowed your focus.

Comment: I'm working on my own, ECS right now.  I can state that I'll be using some hierarchy to generate a default (entity/component/attribute) class that is expanded later to form a more specific type.  This will let my systems look for either a generic class, or a more specific one when they do their processing later.